# Get text from <asp:TextBox in ASP.NET WebForm

Tags: c#, html, jquery, css, asp.net

I'm creating a project to connect ASP.NET WebForm to SQL Server. To insert a text to a table in SQL Server, I'm using `<asp:TextBox` but when I click button to get text in TextBox, this text is nothing.

Here is my workflow: I have 1 page is Administrator.aspx, this page has user control: adminControl.ascx -> Menu.ascx -> NewsControl.ascx -> NewsCategory.ascx

Here is the code:

Administrator.aspx

```
<pre>
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" EnableEventValidation="false" ValidateRequest="false" CodeBehind="Administrator.aspx.cs" Inherits="iFShopOnline.Administrator" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>

</pre>


namespace iFShopOnline
{
    public partial class Administrator : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                Controls.Add(LoadControl("/admin/adminControl.ascx")); 
        }
        public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control)
        {  
        }
    }
}
```

adminControl.ascx

```
<pre>
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="adminControl.ascx.cs" Inherits="iFShopOnline.adminControl" %>
<%@ Register src="../Menu.ascx" tagname="Menu" tagprefix="uc1" %>

    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width:100%;">
    <tr>
        <td style="width:200px;">
            <uc1:Menu ID="Menu1" runat="server" />
        </td>
        <td style="width:10px;">&nbsp;</td>

        <td><asp:PlaceHolder ID="plLoad" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</pre>


namespace iFShopOnline
{
    public partial class adminControl : System.Web.UI.UserControl
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                string s = Request["f"];
                switch (s)
                {
                    case "news":
                        plLoad.Controls.Add(LoadControl("News/NewsControl.ascx"));
                        break;
                    case "product":
                        plLoad.Controls.Add(LoadControl("Products/ProductControl.ascx"));
                        break;
                }
        }
    }
}


<pre>
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Menu.ascx.cs" Inherits="iFShopOnline.Menu" %>
<div><a href="/">Trang chủ</a></div>
<div><a href="Administrator.aspx">Trang quản trị</a></div>
<div><a href="Administrator.aspx?f=news">Tin tức</a></div>
<div><a href="Administrator.aspx?f=product">Sản Phẩm</a></div>
<div><a href="admin/Users/UsersControl.ascx">Tài Khoản</a></div>
<div><a href ="admin/Contacts/ContactControl.ascx">Liên hệ</a></div>
</pre>


namespace iFShopOnline
{
    public partial class Menu : System.Web.UI.UserControl
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

NewsControl.ascx

```
<pre>
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="NewsControl.ascx.cs" Inherits="iFShopOnline.admin.News.NewsControl" %>
Trang News
</pre>


namespace iFShopOnline.admin.News
{
    public partial class NewsControl : System.Web.UI.UserControl
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                Controls.Add(LoadControl("NewsCategory.ascx")); 
        }
    }
}
```

NewsCategory.ascx

```
<pre>
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="NewsCategory.ascx.cs" Inherits="iFShopOnline.admin.News.NewsCategory" %>
<div>DANH SÁCH DANH MỤC</div>
<asp:MultiView ID="mul" runat="server" ActiveViewIndex="0">
    <asp:View ID="v1" runat="server" >

        <div>
            <asp:Repeater ID ="rptNewsCategory" runat="server">
                <HeaderTemplate>
                    <table style="width:100%;">
                        <tr>
                            <td style="width:300px;">Category Name</td>
                            <td style="width:50px;">Order</td>
                            <td style="width:100px;">Active</td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>

                </HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <tr>
                        <td><%#:Eval("vName") %></td>
                        <td><%#: Eval("vOrder") %></td>
                        <td><%#: Eval("Active") %></td>
                    </tr>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    </table>
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
        </div>

        <div ><asp:LinkButton ID="lnkAddNew" runat="server" OnClick="lnkAddNew_Click">Add News</asp:LinkButton></div>


    </asp:View>
    <asp:View ID="v2" runat="server">


                <div>Category Name</div>
                <div><asp:TextBox ID="txtCate" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" CausesValidation ="false"></asp:TextBox></div>


                <div>Order</div>
                <div><asp:TextBox ID="txtOrder" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></div>

                <div>Active</div>
                <div><asp:CheckBox id="chkCheck" runat="server" Checked="true"/></div>

                <div></div>
                <div><asp:Button id="btnAdd" runat="server" OnClick="btnAdd_Click" UseSubmitBehavior="false" CausesValidation="true" /></div>


                <div><asp:Label ID="lblErr" runat="server" Text="Here"></asp:Label></div>

    </asp:View>
</asp:MultiView>
</pre>


namespace iFShopOnline.admin.News
{
    public partial class NewsCategory : System.Web.UI.UserControl
    {
        clsNews _news = new clsNews();
        string sqlConn = "Data Source=xxxx;Initial Catalog=iFsoftOnline;User ID=xxxx;pwd=xxxx";
        SqlConnection conn = null;
        public void openConn()
        {
            if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                conn.Open();
            }
        }
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                LoadData();
            }
        }
       void LoadData()
        {
            rptNewsCategory.DataSource = _news.GetList();
            rptNewsCategory.DataBind();
        }
        protected void lnkAddNew_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            mul.ActiveViewIndex = 1;
        }
        protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {            
                Response.Write("Reasult: " + txtCate.Text);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So where is your problem?

Comment: Which control are you trying to access from which UserControl?

Comment: My problem is protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {            
                Response.Write("Reasult: " + txtCate.Text);
        }

Comment: when i input text into <asp:TextBox and click Button, the Response just : "Reasult: "

Comment: The contents in <asp:TextBox is not show

Comment: i'm using control: <asp:TextBox to input text and <asp:Button to submit text to table in sql server

Comment: In Administrator.aspx, i must set EnableEventValidation = "false" to run page without error, i think this row making error above

Comment: i'm 23 years old, i want to learn about web

Comment: if you are new and want to learn about the web, then please don't start with WebForms - it's practically a dead technology now. Certainly it won't be developed any further, and it's not supported at all in the new .NET Core that Microsoft are now using as the main .NET platform. I would suggest learning something modern like ASP.NET Core MVC or ASP.NET Core Razor Pages (Razor pages is sort of intended as a modern replacement for WebForms, and it's much easier to use as well). Start here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio